# Secure C# Webservice using Active Directory

Tags: c#, web-services, active-directory

I have a simple WebService like 'localhost:52028/Service1.asmx/SayHello?name='username'' to display a string. I have to secure this Webservice using Active Directory so that only valid users would access this service.

I tried the steps in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27554/Authentication-in-web-services-using-C-and-Kerbero), but it has too many configurations I think so, Is there any other simple way to secure a Webservice using ActiveDirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help .You can check different groups

```
 string currentUser = Environment.UserName;
 PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
 GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "YOURUSERSGROUP");
 UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, currentUser);
```

Sample will be like

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Security;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SayHelloClassification
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/Service1/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  [WebMethod(Description = "Call to change classification")]
  public string SayHello()
  {
    string currentUser = Environment.UserName;
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,     
    Environment.UserDomainName);
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "YOURUSERSGROUP");
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, currentUser);

    if (!user.IsMemberOf(group))
    {
      throw new SecurityException("Access Denied: User has no permission to process the   
      request");
    }
    else
    {
      // Authenticated
      // Your Code Goes here
    }
  }
  }
```

You can find detail here its for WCF but you can use it for asmx as i did.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541318/Authenticating-a-Web-service-with-Active-Directory

**You can find your groups going to DOS cmd and enter this command GPRESULT /r**